# Invert the random choice of keys in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a huge np.array called arr with N values and choose 10% of these values randomly by:

```
choice=random.sample(range(N), int(N*percent))  # percent has values 0-1
newarr=arr[choice]
```

N could be over 2 million values.

Actually I also need an array with the other 90% of values. So at the moment I use the following which is very slow:

```
def buildRevChoice(choice, nevents):
        revChoice=[]
        for i in range(N):
            if not i in choice:
                revChoice.append(i)
        return revChoice
```

Can you think of a method to fasten this up?

Comment: Quick optimization: In `buildRevChoice`, create a `set` from `choice` to speed up the lookup.

Comment: Don't use python loops for big arrays at all if you need performance. Use functional programming of python/numpy and vectorization of numpy.

Comment: Yes I know but I didn't found another solution per google. Couldn't think of a reasonable search phrase.

Answer (score 7):

You can just [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) the list, then split it as you like.

```
def choice(N, percent):
    tmp = range(N)
    random.shuffle(tmp)
    cut = int(N * percent)
    return tmp[:cut], tmp[cut:]
```

And you'll get your two lists, the first containing the chosen ones and the second containing the rest.

Comment: not a bad solution; though I am somewhat wary of the performance of random.shuffle. Potentially, random.permutation has better performance. And depending how that is implemented, np.argsort(random.randint()) may be a faster way still to generate a permutation index.

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn I haven't worked using `numpy`, so all I know is the basic python :) Would the O(n) Fisher Yates Shuffle algorithm be a good choice for shuffling?

Comment: Any algorithm you implement yourself will be a bad choice, unless you plan on writing a C extension. Note that I havnt benchmarked shuffle; I just imagine that the most random in-place shuffle algorithm isn't necessarily the most efficient.

Answer (score 3):

If you're OK with the memory overhead of a mask array, this seems to be faster than selecting the other values by index and retains the order of the elements in `are`. Here is what I got with timings from IPython notebook:

```
N = 2000000
arr = random.random(N)
percent = 0.10
```

My solution:

```
%% timeit
choice = random.choice(N, N*percent)
mask = zeros_like(arr, bool)   
mask[choice] = True
newarr = arr[mask]
revchoice = arr[~mask]
```

10 loops, best of 3: 18.1 ms per loop

0605002's solution:

```
tmp = range(N)
random.shuffle(tmp)
cut = int(N * percent)
newarr, revchoice = tmp[:cut], tmp[cut:]
```

1 loops, best of 3: 603 ms per loop

Comment: Thank you very much, that are two very good solutions, I'll check which one is faster. I'm not used to memory problems. In which case I shouldn't use masks?

Comment: This solution (and the other one by 0605002) uses an array that has the same size as `arr`. So if your array is half as big as the available memory, you won't have enough space to create the mask. If you avoid building the mask, you can get by with just 10% more memory for the index array. 2 million points is not that many, though.

Comment: I've updated my answer with timings. My solution is an order of magnitude faster.

Comment: That is really fast compared to my first solution. Thank you very much, that helps a lot. I like retaining the order of the array. Besides: I have to execute that code several times (<10) so the difference between the solutions showed up even more.

Comment: The best way to say "thank you, that helps a lot" on stack overflow is to accept the answer :-)